# MacOSX Bash App Bundle as Sudo

Tags: macos, bash, bundle, sudo

I am working on a simple little mac application which runs a bash script when opened. My problem is, the bash script requires that sudo commands be called! Unfortunately, the app simply crashes when I try to do any sudo commands in the bash.

My app/bundle hierarchy is very simple:

```
myapp.app
--Contents
----MacOs
------myapp (the bash script)
```

That's it.

Seeing as using sudo is obviously not going to work, is there a way for me to make the application ask the user for a password, and then run its bash script AS sudo? Then I could remove the sudo prefixes and everything would theoretically work fine.

Comment: Why your app crash when you try sudo command? I don't understand! Do you have root permissions on the machine?

Comment: Sudo command requires a terminal to be open (in order to enter root password) -- when running bash as an app no terminal can open. This is why I assume it crashes when doing sudo commands. I would basically like to make the app run as though the entire thing were opened via sudo, that way I won't need to have sudo in the bash its self.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that with sandbox, authorization under Mac become difficult (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/01introduction/introduction.html)

Maybe you can find some informations here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html